# GAE+JPA: Transaction not working on Production

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

i got strange thing here. I use JPA for CRUD process in datastore Google App Engine. i use transaction for edit and deleting some entity, but it works well on my development machine but its not working in production even not showing any error in my production log. This is piece of my code :

```
public boolean removeBalance(long id) {
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    try {
        Balance balance = em.find(Balance.class, id);
        if (balance!= null) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.remove(balance);
            List<Balance> listBalance=listBalance(balance.getUrut());
            for(int i=0;i<listBalance.size();i++){
                //update some entity            
            }
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

log just show :

```
2013-04-19 23:33:56.980 (link here) 200 259ms 20kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)     AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
139.0.82.222 - - [19/Apr/2013:09:33:56 -0700] "POST
```

did i make mistake in my code?

UPDATE :

it just didn't working if it update more than 5 records in a transaction and thanks for @DataNucleus notice me that it is limitation from Google App Engine.

Comment: or maybe you didnt look at the log?

Comment: it will success if transaction just update less than 5 record. if any limit for updating more than 5 records in a transaction?

Comment: if you have multipleXG txns enabled then you can use up to 5 entity groups, as per the GAE datastore docs. But is that the problem? The log shows *a lot* more than just 2 lines ... i'm talking log here not console, and at DEBUG level.

Comment: @DataNucleus i try in my development delete a record and update 6 records in same entity was failed. i think it same in production. it said : operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction. how to enable multipleXG txns in JPA?

Comment: Set persistence property datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions to true as per GAE docs

Comment: i did it before.. <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/> but a transaction still cant update more than 5 records..

Comment: As all GAE docs say, that property allows you to use up to 5 entity groups per transaction. Want more than that and you have to split your code into more transactions yourself.